# How to Configure Action Log in Magento 2 Community Edition?

Tags: magento2, admin-panel

Is there any method to View the admin action log in Magento 2 Community Version? I have been looking for it but only found the reference for Magento 2 Enterprise Version.

Answer (score 1):

STEP-BY-STEP PROCESS TO LOG ADMIN ACTIONS IN MAGENTO 2

Please follow the below steps to learn how to log admin actions in your Magento 2 store.

**STEP – 1**
First of all, log in to your admin panel and navigate to Stores > Settings > Configuration.

**STEP – 2**
After that, open the Advanced section and click on Admin.

**STEP – 3**
Next, find the Admin Actions Logging section and do the following:

Select checkboxes for which you want to enable logging the admin actions.
Click on the Save Changes button to finish the process.

Answer (score -1):

You may have a look at the below magento extension which can suit your requirements.

https://marketplace.magento.com/dotsquares-imexport.html

https://marketplace.magento.com/dotsquares-gdpr.html

https://marketplace.magento.com/dotsquares-attributes.html

https://marketplace.magento.com/dotsquares-customernotification.html